# Toolbar won't show up on Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I only have one activity and everything else is a fragment. However, I don't want to have a single toolbar in my main activity to modify in my fragments since only a few of the views will actually have a toolbar.

This is the fragment's XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tbRegister"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="Create an account!"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="30dp">
        ...
        ...
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

OnCreateView:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_register, container, false);
    Toolbar tbRegister = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.tbRegister);
    tbRegister.setTitle("Create an account!");
    ...
    ...
}
```

I can see a grey box to represent the toolbar in the Fragment, but nothing inside it. For now, I just want to display the title. I have tried setting the title in the XML like so:

`android:text="Create an account!"`

And I've also tried assigning the support action bar to the toolbar:

```
Toolbar tbRegister = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.tbRegister);
tbRegister.setTitle("Create an account!");
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(tbRegister);
```

But I just can't get the text to display, any ideas?

Edit:
AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="myapp.raouf.myapp">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Screenshot: 
[image]

Comment: Can you attach the screenshot? also AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @PonsuyambuVelladurai done

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to add a `TextView` as a child of the toolbar:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/tbRegister"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:text="Create an account!"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:text="Create an account!"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Alternatively, you could add the attribute `app:title="Create an account!"` to the toolbar - but this wouldn't be as flexible. I wanted my toolbar title to be centered so I explicitly created a `TextView`.

Doesn't explain why `setTitle()` doesn't work, but worked out for the best I guess.

Answer (score 0):

It will work again by deleting this:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```